# How to retrieve usage on Amazon S3 based on tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We are only implement one bucket for all data stored in S3, there are many data from different organization. Can we retrieve usage from 'foo' organization or 'bar' organization by its 'foo' or 'bar' tag?

**Usecase :**

We deploy a mobile app for our client called 'foo' and 'bar', this app used to upload file (images and videos) contains 'foo' tag, and 'bar' tag based on organization. We use the same API for the app, and same bucket in S3. So I just want to get the metrics like total storage used by 'foo' tag or 'bar' tag. So i can monitor that 'foo' or 'bar' already use N GB.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your use-case? That is, why do you ask, what are you trying to accomplish? When you say "usage", are you referring to billing charges, or are you referring to the number of times objects are accessed?

Comment: Oke @JohnRotenstein i'll do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tagging at the object-level for Amazon S3 was [introduced in March 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-storage-management-update-analytics-object-tagging-inventory-and-metrics/). It allows:

- Lifecycle Management by tag (eg move to Amazon Glacier)
- Access control policies

It does **not** provide metrics based on tags at the object level.

You would need to **write your own script** to retrieve a list of objects and calculate storage based on tag. However, it appears that the only way to retrieve tags on an object is to request *for each individual object*. This means you would be making large quantities of API calls.

<del>An alternative is to use [object metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) against each object. Metadata is returned by the `list-objects` API call, so it would only require one API call per 1000 objects (which is the paging size of returned data).</del>

Finally, you could store the objects in **separate buckets**, which would make it possible to use Amazon CloudWatch metrics. Amazon S3 sends metrics to Amazon CloudWatch for the number of objects and the amount of storage space.

Comment: *"Metadata is returned by the list-objects API call"* I wish.  Check that?  ListObjects only has key, last modified, size, storage class, and etag.  Same for ListObjectsV2.  Metadata and tags are similarly-limited, in that they can't be scanned in blocks of *n*, they can only be fetched individually, unless I've overlooked something significant.

Comment: Ah! Quite so! The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) said *"Metadata about each object returned."* but it turns out it is a different type of metadata. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to the current documentation you can only use bucket tags for cost allocation reports.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketBilling.html

However with CloudWatch you can use a metric configuration with an object tag filter which returns metrics for only those tagged S3 objects. It may be limited to request metrics. You will need to use the new S3 Console and instructions are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/metrics-configurations.html

Also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Lambda function that executes on upload events in s3 that can records the metadata about the object into a database like Dynamodb or mysql. And then a separate lambda function on delete events in the s3 bucket. Then you can run analytics on the database instead of trying to use a lot of API calls to s3.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html